# How to add text to a plotly boxplot in r

Tags: r, plotly, boxplot, outliers

I would like to mark the outlier that appears on my chart writing where it is. Is this possible with plotly?

The code of my graph is here:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1234)

plot_ly(y = rnorm(50), type = 'box') %>%
    add_trace(y = rnorm(50, 1)) %>%
layout(title = 'Box Plot',
       xaxis = list(title = "cond", showgrid = F),
       yaxis = list(title = "rating"))
```

Comment: Have you had a look at https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/ ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use this template. But, it doesn't work with the boxplot type. I want to add a text just in a one outlier in my chart.

Comment: I have the same doubt as this guy here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266253/show-observations-that-are-outliers-in-plot-ly?newreg=ae6620ac5a044995a94c257e50760f55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you tried and what's not working, but one way to identify outliers is to use `boxplot.stats()` and then you can use that information to add annotations.

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(1234)
d <- rnorm(50)
d2 <- rnorm(50, 1)

plot_ly(y = d, type = 'box') %>%
  add_trace(y = d2) %>%
  layout(title = 'Box Plot',
         xaxis = list(title = "cond", showgrid = F),
         yaxis = list(title = "rating"),
         annotations = list(
           x = -0.01, 
           # use boxplot.stats() to get the outlier's y coordinate
           y = boxplot.stats(d)$out, 
           text = "Outlier",
           showarrow = FALSE,
           xanchor = "right"
         )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I started learning R last week. Now it works. I didn't used boxplot.stats () to identify the outlier, so it didn't work out. I tried to put the coordinates of the outlier manually.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547448/r-for-the-same-code-labels-q1-median-appear-on-one-computer-but-dont-appea thanks!